# How to replace any directory name with other directory name in the URL using htaccess in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to replace or remove portfolio from the URL using `.htaccess` file.

**Current URL** - http://example.com/test/example/portfolio/blahblahblah/

**New URL** - http://example.com/test/example/case-study/blahblahblah/

Comment: Can you check this `RewriteRule ^/?portfolio/(.*)$ http://example.com/test/example/case-study/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490256/i-want-to-change-portfolio-to-case-study-in-the-url-using-htaccess-how-can-i-ac, which you asked only three hours ago. Please do not create duplicates, especially not in such a short time frame, but address the feedback you got on your original question instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to change portfolio to case-study in the url using htaccess, how can I achieve this using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490256/i-want-to-change-portfolio-to-case-study-in-the-url-using-htaccess-how-can-i-ac)